# Writing TextMate bundle

Tags: macos, textmate, textmatebundles

I want to write a bundle for TextMate, where to start?

Comment: http://wiki.macromates.com/Main/Bundles ?

Answer (score 1):

When writing the [FileMaker TextMate Bundle](http://code.google.com/p/filemaker-textmate-bundle/people/list), I found [TextMate: Power Editing for the Mac](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/textmate/textmate) quite helpful. Other than that, take a look at one of the simpler existing bundles. How you go about writing your bundle depends on if it's for a language that doesn't yet have a bundle (so that you need to define the language syntax) or if you just want to add functionality to TextMate, in which case you'll probably be writing commands and snippets. Commands are fairly simple, since they're just scripts, and you can use whatever language works for you (Ruby, PHP, Perl, etc.).